# Is there a hotel search engine(website) that allows to filter results by room size?

Tags: online-resources, hotels

I search for it for years, That would be really useful

Comment: Size as in square meters? Never seen that but generally they allow searching on number of beds and some on number of rooms (for suites)

Comment: I don't think most hotels publish the floor area of their rooms, so there's no way for a search engine to even have this data.  And there may be significant variance in area between rooms of the same class at a given hotel.  I don't really see how this would be possible with existing hotel reservation infrastructure.

Comment: @NateEldredge Booking.com often shows it in room listings